# Flymake quits right ahead after loading with js2-mode

Tags: javascript, emacs, flymake, js2-mode

When opening .js files, js2-mode and, subsequently, flymake-js is
automatically loaded. But flymake unloads right ahead with the message

> Toggling flymake-mode off; better pass an explicit argument.

However, when enabling it manually, using `M-x flymake-mode`, it keeps
activated.  Has anybody encountered similar behavior and has fixed it?

**My setup:**
I followed the instructions on [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript#toc3) to set up Flymake to work with
the most recent [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/downloads/detail?name=js2-20090723b.el&can=2&q=) with a little modification:

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook '(lambda () (flymake-js-load)))
```

instead of

```
(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook '(lambda () (flymake-js-load)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, somewhere in your hook, there is a statement like :

```
     (flymake-mode t)
```

you need to change it to :

```
     (flymake-mode 1)
```

---

I read the documentation on flymake-mode.  It says:

```
flymake-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `flymake.el'.
(flymake-mode &optional ARG)

Minor mode to do on-the-fly syntax checking.
When called interactively, toggles the minor mode.
With arg, turn Flymake mode on if and only if arg is positive.
```

If and only if the arg is *positive*.  Not non-nil.  But the page on 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript which suggests a definition for flymake-js-load, shows `(flymake-mode t)` .

That seems wrong.